# Simpy: How to catch the return value of a simpy process

Tags: simpy

Imagine that I have this scenario:

```py
def my_process(env, run_length):
    count = 0
    while True:
        env.timeout(1)
        count += 1
        if env.now >= run_length:
            break

    return count

my_env = simpy.Environment()

count = my_env.process(my_process(my_env, 100))

my_env.run(100)
```

If I print the value of count it will return the the generator itself and not the count of the number of events triggered by the generator which is what I want. I could pass an object to my_process and change its state according to count, but isn't there another way?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **yield** and another process for getting return value. (Environment's run time should be more than 100).

```
import simpy

def my_process(env, run_length):
    count = 0;
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(1);
        count += 1;
        if env.now >= run_length:
            break;

    return count;

def first_process(env, run_length):
    return_value = yield env.process(my_process(env, run_length));
    print("return value: ", return_value);

my_env = simpy.Environment();
my_env.process(first_process(my_env, 100));
my_env.run(101);
```

output in simpy 4:

```
return value:  100
```

Comment: Someone please delete those `;`s ;)